# How to include Adobe Analytics in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone, adobe-analytics

I know cn1 has native [support for Google Analytics](https://www.codenameone.com/analytics-api.html). How can we get the same for Adobe Analytics?

The AppMeasurement java API is described [here](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/java/oms_sc_appmeasure_java.pdf).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The documents you link pertain to JavaSE/EE not for mobile or web so I'm not sure how practical they are. You need to look for web service based documents and implement the required calls into the webservice.

You can also use the JavaEE version on your server and open a webservice yourself or use a native OS SDK if available.

To bind it to Codename One you can derive the [AnalyticsService](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/analytics/AnalyticsService.java) class and just call the `init` method with your own derived instance. Then calls to visit can be mapped to the Adobe implementation.